# Curly Brackets default to next line on Sublime Text 2

Tags: php, sublimetext2

Having used Visual Studios for the past few months I have really liked my curly brackets on the next line.  Now I am doing a lot of PHP and I prefer Sublime Text 2 for PHP.  Is there a way to configure Sublime Text 2 to default the curly brackets to the next line?

Comment: "Default" as in from the snippets? It only default to what you type.

Comment: so if I accidentally add the curly bracket inline with lets say a function, it will automatically drop the bracket to the next line

Comment: You can edit the snippets

Comment: No, I just got used to doing it manually